# If I zero initialize a struct at the start of a loop using {0}, will it be zeroed out every iteration?

Tags: c

Let's assume that I have a `for` loop, and a very large struct as a stack variable:

```
for (int x=0 ; x <10; x++)
{
    MY_STRUCT structVar = {0};
    …code using structVar…
}
```

Will every compiler actually zero out the struct at the start of every loop? Or do I need to use `memset` to zero it out?

This is a very large struct and I want to allocate it on the stack, and I need to make sure every member of it is zeroed out at the start of every iteration. So do I need to use `memset`?

I can manually inspect the executable that I compile, but I need to make sure if there is any standard for this, or it just depends on the compiler.

Note that this code does compile. I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: If (assuming the loop has `{` braces `}`) you put *before* that definition, say `structVar.member = 42;` the compiler will tell you the `struct` does not exist. It gets created in the next line.

Comment: Does this code actually compile (without braces)?

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure if i follow, why would i try to access the struct members before i defined it? Note that as of right now i am not getting any compiler error, or any problems, and i am using visual studio, but wanted to make sure if this depends on compiler or not.

Comment: @jarmod Yes it does compile, i am using Visual studio, and it works as intended as well, but i am not sure if it depends on compiler or not. using VS2019

Comment: I mean *it does not exist* and neither does any previous value that needed zeroing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes its confusing, but if the compiler is really smart, it should zero it out in every loop (it does make sense in that regard when you think about it)

Comment: @pmg So all C compilers are smart enough to understand that they need to zero out this struct, no matter how large it is, in the start of every loop right? Because i wrote this code, and for a second thought maybe since this is a stack variable, and the location of it on the stack probably won't change (even tho for every loop a new one is defined), maybe it only zero initialize it at the first loop only. How do compilers zero it out without using memset tho?

Comment: Yes, all standard conforming compilers *with no relevant bugs* will zero out everything, recursively if needed. As to **how**... that's a quality of implementation issue :-)

Comment: @OneAndOnly It has nothing to do with being smart. It is just the defined behavior of the program. Actually, a smart compiler may _omit_ (part of) the zeroing in the emitted code if it notices that you don't modify (part of) the storage in the loop body as an optimization. But that must not affect the observable behavior of a valid C program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Will every compiler actually zero out the struct at the start of every loop?*

Any compiler that conforms to the C Standard will do this. From [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### 6.8 Statements and blocks
>
> …
> 3    A *block* allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped into
> one syntactic unit. ***The initializers of objects that have automatic
> storage duration***, and the variable length array declarators of
> ordinary identifiers with block scope, ***are evaluated and the values
> are stored in the objects*** (including storing an indeterminate value in
> objects without an initializer) ***each time the declaration is reached
> in the order of execution***, as if it were a statement, and within each
> declaration in the order that declarators appear.

In the case of a `for` or `while` loop, a declaration/initializer inside the loop's scope block is reached *repeatedly* on each and every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

See [6.2.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4), paragraph 6:

> If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each
> time the declaration or compound literal is reached in the execution
> of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the
> declaration is reached

Comment: How do compilers zero it out without using memset tho? Considering that its a stack variable, the location the struct variable will most likely stay at the same place (from esp) in the stack, so if its really large, how do compilers zero it out at every loop?  for example if its 1000 bytes on the stack, it needs to zero out every byte of that at the start of every loop.

Comment: @OneAndOnly — the compiler can do it however it likes; it simply has to do it.  It probably emits inline code equivalent to `memset()`; it might do the same for `memset()` itself.  The initialization code won't be less efficient than `memset()` unless the compiler is seriously deficient.

Comment: @OneAndOnly as pmg metioned in his comment, that is a quality of implementation detail.  Probably, different compilers do it slightly differently.  Practically, it is probably safe to think of it as if it does a memset.

Comment: This quote is rather irrelevant as it only describes what happens if you don't initialize the code, as opposed to if you do like in the OP's code. In which case the rules for struct initialization are what matters, and they are the same no matter the object's storage duration, as long as at least one member is initialized explicitly.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure I follow your comment.  The statement is "If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration...is reached".  It seems applicable.

Answer (score 1):

> Will every compiler actually zero out the struct at the start of every loop?

Yes, or it will produce machine code with equivalent functionality ("observable behavior") as if you had performed a zero-out.

As long as you initialize one single member in the struct, then the rest of them will get set to zero/null ("as if they had static storage duration"). Similarly, any padding bytes added to the struct by the compiler will get set to zero. This is guaranteed by the C standard ISO:9899:2018 6.7.9 §10, §19 and §21.

Generally, the place where the zero-out actually occurs in the resulting executable depends on how the data is used. If you for example zero the struct at the beginning of the loop body, then write to various members and print it all in the end of the loop body, the compiler don't have many other choices but to zero-out everything at each lap of the loop. Example:

```
for (int x=0 ; x <10; x++)
{
    MY_STRUCT structVar = {0};
    ...
    structVar.foo = a;
    structVar.bar = b;
    printf("%d %d\n", structVar.foo, structVar.bar);
}
```

On the other hand, the compiler might in this case be smart enough to realize that the struct is just a pointless middle man and replace this all with the equivalent `printf("%d %d\n", a, b);`, meaning that the struct would be removed entirely from the machine code.

Overall, discussing optimizations like this can't be done without a specific use-case, compiler and target system.

---

> Or do I need to use memset to zero it out?

No. `MY_STRUCT structVar = {0};` is functionally 100% equivalent of `memset(structVar, 0, sizeof structVar);`.

---

> This is a very large struct and I want to allocate it on the stack

That's a different matter than initialization. It is indeed unwise to allocate large objects on the stack. In that case consider replacing it with for example this:

```
MY_STRUCT* structVar = malloc(sizeof *structVar);
for (int x=0 ; x <10; x++)
{
  memset(structVar, 0, sizeof *structVar);  
  ...
}
free(structVar);
```

Comment: But `memset` is theoretically not 100% equivalent on all conforming plaforms, for the bit representation issues mentioned by @IanAbbott, is it? And I think at least in the past there were platforms with such unusual representations.

Comment: @user17732522 Padding bytes are guaranteed not to be trap representations. However, on exotic theoretical systems where the struct contains pointers and null pointers do not have the all-zeroes representation, then indeed memset isn't equivalent. However, designing for portability with exotic/fictional systems that may not exist in the real world is a huge waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

For the variables (of automatic storage class) defined within the body of a loop, the variables are (notionally) recreated for each iteration of the loop and have indeterminate values for each iteration if not initialized.

Regarding use of the `{0}` initializer for an object with automatic storage duration, note the following:

- As per [6.7.9/19](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19) and [6.7.9/21](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21),  elements of the object that have no explicit initializer will be initialized implicitly the same as object of static storage duration. As per [6.7.9/10](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10), those elements will be initialized to value zero or a null pointer as appropriate, and any padding will be initialized to zero bits.

Using `memset(ptr, 0, size)` sets `size` bytes from address `ptr` onwards to 0, but note the following:

- For some unusual execution environments, a pointer object with all bytes zero might not represent a null pointer value (so might not compare equal to 0).
- For some unusual execution environments, a floating point object with all bytes zero might not represent a valid floating point value or might not compare equal to 0.0.

In summary, using the `{0}` initializer is the most portable way to set all elements of the object to compare equal to 0, and to set all padding bits or bytes to 0. Using `memset` instead is generally OK except for some weird execution environments.

Comment: No this is not correct. For any struct where at least one member is initialized, the rest is initialized as per 6.7.9/10. "As if they had static storage duration." Explicitly: "_if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
and any padding is initialized to zero bits;"_"

Comment: @Lundin I've tried to clarify it by restricting my answer to objects of automatic storage class/duration.

Comment: @Lundin On closer reading, particularly 6.7.9/21, I think you are correct. I shall amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: @IanAbbott 6.7.9/19 and 6.7.9/21 both, also pointing back to 6.7.9/10.

Comment: What is not safe however, is to declare an object of automatic storage, don't initialize it, but assign members one by one. In that scenario the padding bytes might contain anything.